# DATE_ADD Function

Tags: sql, syntax, dateadd

A glitch in code on my website caused the start date and end date in an sql table to be set to the same day for my online member directory.  I have the code glitch corrected, but now need a way to fix the data in the database.  I am trying to add a certain number of months (12, 18, 24, etc) to the end_date column depending on the package column.  I only want to do this when the start_date column is equal to the end_date column.  I have a query started, but keep running into an invalid syntax message.  Can someone help?  My sql is below

```
UPDATE porye_jbusinessdirectory_orders
SET end_date = DATE_ADD(months,12,end_date)
WHERE start_date = end_date
AND package_id = 1;
```

Comment: As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Please update tags of your question to reflect the flavour or SQL (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET end_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 12 MONTH)`

This is for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `DATEADD` instead.

Your syntax seems like `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )` which is not the syntax for `DATE_ADD`

```
UPDATE porye_jbusinessdirectory_orders
SET end_date = DATEADD(month, 12 ,end_date)
WHERE start_date = end_date
AND package_id = 1;
```

Check more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)